# VBA SQL, SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to make a connection from Excel VBA to SQl Server to fetch the data.
while opening the Connection, I am getting this error
`SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.`

below is the code snippet

```
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."
con.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=WWWWW;User ID=ZZZZZ; Password=YYYYY;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600
```

**Server machine :**

Windows Server 2012 R2, 64 bit OS

SQL SERVER : SQL 2017

**Client machine:**

It doesn't have SQL Server or SSMS

Excel 2016 Office 365 is installed

Please share your views on this issue to fix it.

I have tried by modifying the connection string as
`TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19 suggests you might need to install an updated SQL Server driver on the client PC.